# File is not a Windows BMP File

Tags: eclipse, macos, python-2.7, pygame, pydev

I am currently writing a game in Python 2.7.7 and Pygame. I am on a Mac running OS X 10.9, and I am using Eclipse along with the PyDev plugin. In the game, I am loading a PNG file for the game's background. However, whenever I try, it detects the file, but it gives me the error "pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file". Whenever I've used Pygame before I have been able to load PNG files just fine. I also tried exporting the image as a JPG but got the same error. Please note that I know there are similar questions out there, however, most of those solutions only work on Windows. I've tried running the "update Shell profile" command as seen in this question: [pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577114/pygame-error-file-is-not-a-windows-bmp-file), but that didn't work either. Thank you for your time. Here is my code:

```
import sys, pygame

def main():
    HEIGHT = 500
    WIDTH = 500

    window = pygame.display.set_mode((HEIGHT,WIDTH))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Asteroids")

    background = pygame.image.load("images/background.png")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        window.blit(background,(0,0))

        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried just reinstalling pygame completely?

Comment: I have. I believe it is the version of pygame but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on a mac, but I have two thoughts:

First: I see no pygame.init(), which i learned should allways come first.
Second: You could try:

```
background = pygame.image.load("images/background.jpg").convert()
```

this convert() saved me some headache in the past.
Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I am on mac and met the same problems few days ago.
The problem is that

1. you should make pygame.image.get_extended() returns 1. So u might need some image library such PIL
2. your pygame might be corrupted, so u 'd better reinstall pygame. In OSX, just find out your python's site-packages' path and delete the pygame folder. And reinstall pygame by home-brew or from website. As for me, my site-packages' path is  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
3. After completing the above two points, I successfully make my pygame run with png images.